# Why is the prefix "Trans" shortened to "X"?

Tags: abbreviations, prefixes

In technical literature as well as aircraft user interfaces where there is not enough space to write the whole word, the prefix "trans" is shortened to "x".

> Transmit -> Xmit 
> Transfer -> Xfer

I am interested to know what is the origin of this. I am curious because "Ex" and "Trans" do not have a similar sound.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**X** is commonly used to refer to *cross* because of its shape of two lines crossing.

*[Trans-](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/trans?q=trans-)* means *cross/across*. *Trans-* and *[cross-](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/learner-english/cross_1)* are interchangeable in many cases.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X) (emphasis mine):

> In abbreviations, it can represent *trans-* (e.g. *XMIT* for 'transmit', *XFER* for 'transfer'), *cross-* (e.g. *X-ing* for 'crossing', *XREF* for 'cross-reference'), *Christ-* as shorthand for the labarum (e.g. *Xmas* for 'Christmas', *Xian* for 'Christian'), the *crys-* in 'crystal' (*XTAL*), or various words starting with *ex-* (e.g. *XL* for 'extra large', *XOR* for 'exclusive-or').

Example: a transatlantic flight is one that *crosses* the Atlantic, and something that is transdermal crosses through the skin.

The *trans-* in *transmit* and *transfer* is analogous to *transatlantic*.

Crossing a *mit* or a *fer* makes perfect sense.

- *-Mit* is from the Latin *mittere* which means *to send*.
- *-Fer* is from the Latin *ferre* which means *to bear or carry*.

'[Transmit](https://www.lexico.com/definition/transmit)' often means *to send across something or over a specific medium* and '[transfer](https://www.lexico.com/definition/transfer)' can be *to carry across from one to another*.

Therefore *trans-* is often replaced with *X-* in certain words.

Comment: to add to the confusion, in electronics XTAL is the schematic designation for (quartz) crystals. crossing, christmas, crystal, X fits it all...

Comment: also, OP mentioned aircraft interfaces. Both Airbus and Boeing have cockpit controls where WX stands for weather. X seems to be a wildcard placeholder for almost anything. what do we make of that?

Comment: @dlatikay X in "Christmas" comes from an entirely different derivation, Greek chi.

Comment: @dlatikay is the "X" in WX of the same origin as the lowercase "x" in Rx (prescriptions)?

Comment: $x$ as a placeholder for some unexpanded information is mathematical, and thence to engineering, and thence to aircraft. @dlatikay

Comment: I think saying it "is fine and doesn't change the meaning" is a weird description - very few people will read the abbreviation "xfer" and think "ah, yes, a cunning pun with a symbolic cross and the Latin root _ferre_, this is clearly a word meaning _carry across_". Rather, they will read it as a conventional abbreviation for _English_ words, and the connection of the prefix _trans-_ to "cross" explains the _origin_ of that convention.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have always understood that the X in Christmas is from the Christian religious symbol representing the cross. By extension, the X is also used for the similar sounding part of crystal etc.

Comment: @DavidR The X in Christmas is from Χριστός; the similarity to a cross is coincidental but probably widely used symbolically.

Comment: @dlatikay The suffix -x in TX (transmitter), RX (receiver), WX (weather), DX ((long-)distance), etc. (as well as XMIT and XTAL) were popularized as abbreviations in the days of Morse code, when radio operators (especially amateurs) discussed technical matters and wanted to keep messages as short as possible.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-: Correct, first letters of Christ's name in Greek are _chi_ and _ro_ (fun tangential fact: Belgium has catholic co-ed scouts, called "the chiro" in reference to the chi and ro in Christ's name). However, the Greeks and Romain did also use _chi_ to refer to cross shapes, such as the [chiasmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus). So while the roots are technically different, there is some indirect connection between them.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to the other edifying answers and comments: from an information-theory viewpoint, given the rarity of initial "x" in English words, the presence of it (especially if unpronounceable) is a clear signal that there is something at play slightly out of the ordinary, *and* it will not be easily mistaken for anything else. That is, information-theory-wise, the chance of misunderstanding is low (more technically/precisely, the error-correction properties of this usage are excellent).

Comment: This explanation works both for Xmit and TX abbreviations for "transmit".

Comment: The chance of *confusion* with something else is low; the chance of misunderstanding without context or prior knowledge is still high.

Comment: @chepner, indeed, but/and the reader previously unacquainted with the usage will _know_ that they are unacquainted with it, as opposed to mistaking it for something else, I'd think.

Answer (score 5):

Oddly enough, '**Tx**' is used to describe 'a transmitter' or 'to transmit something' and is very much relevant in electronics domain. Similarly, '**Rx**' describes 'a receiver' or 'to receive something/reception of signal'. Here is a picture which shows Tx and Rx use in electronics:

[image]

[Picture source](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-communication/wiring-and-hardware)

Comment: This is because a lot of computer nerds have trouble spelling "tarsn".

Comment: This doesn't explain why the prefix “Trans” is shortened to “X”, which is what the original question asked.

Comment: @KillingTime Yes, the original question has been answered excellently by Decapitated Soul. I just mentioned an additional point that transmit can be shortened to both 'Xmit' and 'Tx'; the latter being relevant in electronics domain.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it's good to note. You could leave a comment on the question instead.

Comment: Combining ideas in this and the accepted answer, RX/TX could be considered as an abbreviation for "Receive aCROSS the wire" and "Transmit aCROSS the wire" (or indeed "... through CROSSed wires" - as shown in your diagram. No idea of actual historical origin, so this is possibly a backronym.

Comment: @HotLicks And recieve ...

Comment: And all this time I thought that "Tx/Rx" had something to do with a prescription written in Texas... :/

Answer (score 3):

OED:

> **trans-**, prefix

> **Etymology: The Latin preposition trans, *across*, to or on the farther side of, beyond, over’, also used in combination, (1) with verbs, (2) adjectives (3) the neames of geographical features and names, etc.**

e.g. transcribe, transcript, transcription, tranship, transport, transmarine, transmural, transatlantic,

The shape of the letter X is described as **a cross**: The letter is formed by one line crossing another:

> b. **The letter considered with regard to its shape: chiefly attributive and in other combinations. Hence identified with a cross. X's and O's: the game of noughts and crosses. X chair, a chair in which the underframe resembles the letter X in shape; so X-frame (usually attributive).**

> 1976   Country Life 27 May (Suppl.) 486/1   *Late 18th century wheel-back armchairs with saddle seats and X-frame legs.*

> **d. [the letter or mark 'X'] Used to mark a location on a map or the like; esp. in X marks the spot and variants.**

> 1918   J. M. Barrie Echoes of War 5   *In the rough sketch drawn for to-morrow's press, ‘Street in which the criminal resided’..you will find Mrs. Dowey's home therein marked with a X.*