# Why is "transaction" shortened as "xact"?

Tags: abbreviations

I came upon the shortcut ***xact*** standing for *transaction* in [Postgres database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transactions.html):

> The word transaction is often abbreviated as *xact*.

Then I found that this is probably not Postgres-specific, and it is also used [elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/15fasco/comment/juc09lb/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button):

> TR: Used in the banking industry.
> TRX: Used in the cryptocurrency industry.
> **XACT**: Used in the business world.

How is "XACT" similar to "Transaction" so it became its abbreviation?

Comment: Trans = across. Cross = x. Never heard of 'xact' myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can "trans" be replaced with an x?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200356/why-can-trans-be-replaced-with-an-x) And see [this duplicate question which has more details](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541226/why-is-the-prefix-trans-shortened-to-x).

Comment: "xmit" has been used in data communications as an abbreviation for "transmit" for decades, as well.